# node mosca mqtt Browserify I don't get message in the broker

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I'm just playing around with mqtt && mosca

I've followed this steps:

```
npm install -g browserify // install browserify 
cd node_modules/mqtt
npm install . // install dev dependencies 
browserify mqtt.js -s mqtt > browserMqtt.js
```

### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./browserMqtt.js"></script>
      <script>
        var client = mqtt.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 1884 }); 
        client.subscribe("presence");

        client.on("message", function(topic, payload) {
          console.log([topic, payload].join(": "));
          client.end();
        });

        client.publish("presence", "hello world!");
    </script> 
    </body>

</html>
```

### server.js

```
var mosca = require('mosca')

//1883
var settings = {
  port: 1884
};

//here we start mosca
var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
server.on('ready', setup);

// fired when the mqtt server is ready
function setup() {
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running')
}

// fired whena  client is connected
server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
  console.log('client connected', client.id);
});

// fired when a message is received
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
  console.log('Published MIO: ', packet.payload);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
server.on('subscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('subscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client subscribes to a topic
server.on('unsubscribed', function(topic, client) {
  console.log('unsubscribed : ', topic);
});

// fired when a client is disconnecting
server.on('clientDisconnecting', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnecting : ', client.id);
});

// fired when a client is disconnected
server.on('clientDisconnected', function(client) {
  console.log('clientDisconnected : ', client.id);
});
```

but if I run

```
node server
```

and than I go to my index.html I don't see any message
in the console window where I've run the server.

With this (it's quite the same) I can see the message

### client.js

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')

var client = mqtt.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 1884 });

client.subscribe('presence');

console.log('Client publishing.. ');
client.publish('presence', 'Client 1 is alive.. Test Ping! ' + Date());

client.end();
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: I didn't think native client would be able to open a normal socket from the browser to the broker. If you use the Paho client it will use MQTT over websockets.

Answer (score 1):

This page explains it well: https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets

Looking at your code you need to allow the mosca server to handle Websockets.  Here is what you should change for your server settings.

**updates to server.js:**

```
var settings = {
    port: 1884,
    http: {
        port: 3000,
        bundle: true,
        static: './'
    }
};
```

**updates to index.html:**

```
var client = mqtt.connect({ host: 'ws://localhost', port: 3000 });
```

Comment: Hello psiphi75, I'm getting the same issue. Updated my server.js and index.html as you told, but nothing has changed. Also getting an Error "EADDRINUSE". 
p.s. I used app.listen('3000', function() {console.log('Server listening on : 3000'});

If I remove this line my ionic app is not launching. all the apis are throwing 404 not found error. Any clue?
Thanks,

Comment: @KaushickGope I don't know much about your configuration, but EADDRINUSE means that something else is already listening on port 3000.  You can try another port, or close the process that has port 3000 open.  Note, a 404 error means something is running and giving you an error.

Comment: I know the meaning of EADDRINUSE, and I also know why this is giving. In mosca settings I've added port 3000 in http config (as you told), and also running my main node server at 3000 port (as I mentioned). If I remove the http part from mosca settings, all the apis are working fine. Did you get my point now?